# AngularJS custom directive $watch not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a demo application with two controllers communicating through a service containing some data. It is a kind of contacts book. A user can edit selected person from the list.

The data is stored in array of objects and I use a custom directive to perform some manipulations with that objects' text properties.

The problem is that a text rendered in the list using the custom directive is not updated on model change (when typing something in name fields) while a text that is placed using {{}} changes while typing.

Here is a sample showing a problem:

js

```js
var contacts = angular.module('contacts', []);

contacts.service('database', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    db : [
    {person:{fName:"John", lName:"Williams"}, phone:"11111111111"},
    {person: {fName:"Sara", lName:"Lewis"}, phone:"222222222"},
    {person: {fName:"Lana", lName:"Watson"}, phone:"33333333333"},
    {person: {fName:"John", lName:"Smith"}, phone:"4444444444"}  
    ],  
    selectedPerson : null,
    setSelected : function (i) {
      this.selectedPerson = i;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('selected');
    }
  }
}]);

 contacts.controller("listCtrl", function($scope, database) {
  $scope.list = database.db;
  $scope.getSelected = function() {
    return database.selectedPerson;
  };
  $scope.setSelected = function(i) {
    database.setSelected(i);
  }; 
});

contacts.controller("editorCtrl", function($scope, database) {
  $scope.editing = database.selectedPerson;
  $scope.$on('selected', function(event) {
    $scope.editing = database.selectedPerson;
  });
});

contacts.directive('personName', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope:{
      personName: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function(){return scope.personName;}, function(obj) {
        var fullName = obj.fName + " " + obj.lName;
        elem.text(fullName);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

html

```html
<div ng-app="contacts">
  <div class='list' ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in list"
      ng-click="$parent.setSelected(i)"
      ng-class="{'sel': ($parent.getSelected() === i)}">
      <span person-name="i.person"></span>, {{i.phone}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='edit'  ng-controller="editorCtrl">
    First name: <input type="text" ng-model='editing.person.fName'> <br>
    Last name: <input type="text"  ng-model='editing.person.lName'> <br>
    Phone: <input type="text"  ng-model='editing.phone'> <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ejnhuqf9

Maybe the problem is with $watch, but everything seems to be ok. Any suggestions?

P.S. In real app I need to use the directive to do more complex text manipulation than just concatenation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set the third parameter of [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) (objectEquality) to true:

```
  scope.$watch(function(){return scope.personName;}, function(obj) {
    var fullName = obj.fName + " " + obj.lName;
    elem.text(fullName);
  }, true);
```

You might want to change the name of the property to person, to remind yourself that it is the entire object, not just a string name.

Comment: Also you won't need a function to return `personName` to watch. Can use `scope.$watch('personName', function(obj){...}, true);`

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. I know about a function or string as a first parameter here. I just forgot to change it back from function to simpler string parameter after testing.